# How to resolve this Java Unsupported Class Warning

Tags: java, deploying

warning:

> javax\servlet\RequestDispatcher.class(javax\servlet:RequestDispatcher.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\ServletException.class(javax\servlet:ServletException.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\http\HttpServlet.class(javax\servlet\http:HttpServlet.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\http\HttpServletRequest.class(javax\servlet\http:HttpServletRequest.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\http\HttpServletResponse.class(javax\servlet\http:HttpServletResponse.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\GenericServlet.class(javax\servlet:GenericServlet.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning: javax\servlet\Servlet.class(javax\servlet:Servlet.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\ServletConfig.class(javax\servlet:ServletConfig.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\annotation\WebServlet.class(javax\servlet\annotation:WebServlet.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\http\Cookie.class(javax\servlet\http:Cookie.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\http\HttpSession.class(javax\servlet\http:HttpSession.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\ServletResponse.class(javax\servlet:ServletResponse.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>   warning:
>   javax\servlet\ServletRequest.class(javax\servlet:ServletRequest.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
>   by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded. 13
>   warnings

Comment: can you also share your code? there's no way we can guess the problem like this

Answer (score 2):

It is Java version issue. Just update the JDK. 
I believe you import this project from somewhere else. So if it is not possible to update java, try to clean it and build again.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a newer JDK. The library you are trying to use was compiled with a newer version than the one you have installed locally, thus they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error and the issue was in pom:
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-compiler-plugin
                2.5.1
                
                    1.6
                    1.6
                    -Xlint:all
                    true
                    true

Just removed this part and it worked